# iOS: How to get twillio voice & video call logs like missed calls etc

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, twilio

I am implementing the chat, voice & video call feature using Twillio SDK in one of my application. I don't know how can I get the missed call logs in Twillio. I have read the documentation. May be I am missing something. Please help if anyone had done this.

Comment: what have you tried already?

Comment: I am looking for the solution, didn't tried anything.